# orchard - Can a form contain many content types?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using Orchard 1.6 CMS I was wondering is it possible to create a kind of system flow with 'Content Types'

For the purpose of an example: If I had 3 separate 'Content Types' (1)A Customer registration page (2)A List of questions regarding the customers company (3)Details about the employees of the company.

Then say I set up a 'Form', where ATM I can only choose one 'Content Type' to display...Is it possible to setup some sort of form that uses the 3 content types. Which overall completes this particular user registration process.

So one page would load after the previous one is complete and button clicked.
Then after the 3 separate pages are complete they would appear as one page from top to bottom allowing the customer to confirm everything to complete registration.

NOTE:Is this what the workflow module in v1.7 does?

Thanks

Comment: This is possible by building a custom controller. I don't know of an easier way.  Are you trying to avoid that method for some reason?

Comment: no not at all just thought there might be a way to use the UI in the dashboard to create it instead of manually creating a custom controller

Comment: I think that will end up being the only option, but let's see if anyone else comes up with anything.

Comment: What does the workflow module in v1.7 entail....is that what I am looking for? one process after the other kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Workflows will not do this for you. What you're looking for is some sort of wizard engine, which could be driven by a workflow. But you will have t create some custom Activities and controllers that collect data and present the final page. As far as I know we don't have anything like this as of yet, but it would be a great addition.